# How to make a selection from two tables yii2

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

My request to the database:

```
query = new Query();

$messages = $query->select(['name', 'message', 'date'])->from(['`user`','`message`'])->where('`user`.id = `message`.id_user AND id_addressee = '.$id.' AND id_user = '.Yii::$app->user->id)->orderBy('date')->all();

in view I make a selection like this:
<?php foreach($messages as $mess): ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <?= Html::encode("{$mess->user->name}") ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?= Html::encode("{$mess->message}") ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?= Html::encode("{$mess->date}") ?>
                </td>
            </tr><?php endforeach; ?>
```

All fields are empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "in view I make a selection like this:" doesn't look like valid code to me. Are you writing in pseudo-code or are these keywords elsewhere defined?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have relation declared.

Like:

```
class User extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public function rules(){
        return [
            [['name'], 'string'],
        ];
    }
    public function getMessage(){
        return $this->hasOne(Message::className(), ['user_id' => 'id']);
    }
}
```

Then:

```
  $record = User::find()
        ->joinWith('message')
        ->all();
```